# Keeping Div in row

Tags: html, css

It looks like an easy implementation but some how not working. I have a header inside it I am trying to position 3 elements left, middle and right horizontally. Vertical these elements will be aligned in middle.
Refer [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/himanshuy/rb0s1kLe/) for complete code.
**CSS**

```
.head, .foot, .middle {
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            left: 0;
        }
        .middle {
            top: 100px;
            bottom: 50px;
            height: 400px;
            background-color: #ffd;
        }
        .head {
            height: 100px;
            top: 0;
            background-color: #000;
            color: #fff;
        }
       .container {
            vertical-align: middle;
        }

        .helpText {

            margin-left: 50%;
        }

        #clock {
            float: right;
        }

        .position {
            position: relative;
        }
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="head">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="position">
            <span>Position: </span>
            <input type="radio" name="position" value="center" id="centerCheckbox" onclick="positionDiv()" checked>Center
            <input type="radio" name="position" value="lowerRight" id="lrCheckbox" onclick="positionDiv()" >Lower Right
        </div>
        <div class="helpText">Press Esc key to hide the window. Enter to show it again.</div>
        <div id="clock"></div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I cannot see any `.foot` and `.middle` in your html. missed?

Comment: Is it .position, .helpText and #clock that you want align right?

Comment: In the html, float:right elements must always go before float:left elements, otherwise they won't stay in the same row - I know it's counter-intuitive but that's how it works.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is what you want. But here it is.

Using `table` on the container and `table-cell` on the individual divs you get a nice centered and vertically aligned div every time.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/neoaptt/zz5ncety/)

```css
body, html {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
.container {
    background-color:yellow;
    width:100%;
    height:200px;
    display:table;
}
.container > div {
    padding:10px;
    text-align:center;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
    <div>Position:
        <input type="radio" name="position" value="center" checked='true' />Center
        <input type="radio" name="position" value="lowerRight" />Lower Right</div>
    <div>Press Esc key to hide the window. Enter to show it again.</div>
    <div>Clock</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not used float to the child of .container, and set the .container to table behavior and the childs to display table-cell with vertical-align: middle, like:

```
.head .container {
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
}
.position, .helpText, #clock {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: auto;
    float: none;
    text-align: center;
    height: 100%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Pik_at/rb0s1kLe/1/

Comment: here I want `.position` in left `.helpText` in middle and `#clock` at the right side.

Comment: This is it on my fiddle

Comment: No it is not horizontally aligned